# После компиляции антивирус блокирует программу

Tags: c

При компиляции и запуске программы столкнулся с тем, что антивирусник Авира отправил файл программы в карантин. А при повторном запуске программы в командной строке пишется вот это:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file Hello1.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

С чем это связано и как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Скорей всего вы пишите нечто, похожее на вирус

Comment: :) согласен, вирусы не стоит писать, отключить антивирус..;)

Comment: Решить проблему получилось удалением Авиры и установкой лицензионного Касперского. Также для профилактики воспользовался вашими советами. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Старайтесь избегать последовательностей "hell", "death", "virus", "trojan", "barminpatch", "linux" и т.п. в названии выполнимых файлов. Для большинства антивирусников название выполнимого файла - это основной критерий, по которому они распознают вирусы.

Comment: @AnT, с чего такая информация? К тому же, hell от hello они должны бы отличать.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦: Это юмор такой был...

Answer (score 3):

У антивируса включен эвристический (читай - параноидальный :)) режим тестирования. А ваша программа, например, лезет в Интернет или делает что-то еще, что антивирусник считает возможной угрозой и по принципу "лучше перебдеть" блокирует вашу программу.

Я в этой ситуации просто программу, которая у меня работает постоянно и ежедневно - внес в исключения, как и рабочую папку, в которой веду разработку новых программ (и только ее - в этой папке и подпапках ничего, кроме моих программ, нет). Думаю, это вполне резонное решение...

Comment: Или аппарат автора уже заражен вирусом, и при появлении нового исполняемого файла, он тут же подвергается инфицированию :) на что и реагирует антивирус.

Comment: Резонным решением является все же проверка блокируемого файла например ОнЛайн антивирусом, с загрузкой на веб ресурс, Др.Вэб, АВП итд вроде имеют такие сервисы.

Comment: @NewView В таком случае антивирус должен реагировать и на сам "заражатель" :) - потому что это тот же антивирус. Кроме того, там - в онлайн-сервисе - часть программ не менее параноидальна...

Comment: сам заражатель может уже внёс сам себя в список исключений, если он там живёт и размножаться :) - как предположение, конечно..

Answer (score 3):

Работа компилятора для антивируса очень похожа на работу классического вируса-дроппера - одно приложение (компилятор) генерирует другое приложение (результат компиляции) и потом его запускает (!!!!), при этом может изменять переменные окружения, читать/писать в память процесса (он же отладчик).

Что именно происходит у Вас? компиляция это всегда препроцессинг, собственно компиляция и линковка. Первые два этапа очень редко вызывают у антивирусов приступы. А вот последний процесс, который генерирует бинарник, очень "подозрительный". И при первой линковке антивирус блокирует приложение, а при второй, когда линковщик снова пытается собрать бинарник, он узнает, что файл не доступен для записи (обращения). Собственно это Вы и наблюдаете.

Что делать? В случае винды внести папку с проектами в спокойный режим ( для некоторых это просто исключить папку).  Не держите свои проекты в папке "мои документы". Лучше сделайте на другом диске (например D) и там делайте все проекты. Это даст кучу плюсов

- короткий путь к файлам проекта
- отсутствие "плохих символов в пути" (кириллицы)
- легко бекапить
- небольшая защита от тупых вирусов, которые обычно шифруют файла на диске C
- браузеры скачивают часто файлы в папку мои документы/Загрузки которая находится как раз на диске С и которую лучше не исключать из проверок антивируса.

Также не забудьте включить папку самого компилятора в список исключений антивируса.

Замена антивируса иногда помогает, но до следующего проекта. Хорошо помогает замена причины вируса - замена ОС. Но это может быть неприемлемым.

На своей виндовой рабочей машине я уже много лет пользуюсь только встроенным антивирусом, все остальные жутко тормозят всю систему. Но при этом нужно аккуратно ходить по интернету.